# How to sort a Collection : List<T>?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, collections

I have this example class:

```
class MyClass
{
   public string name;
   public string name2;
}
```

and I want to make a list of `MyClass` like `List<MyClass> myClass = new List<MyClass>();` but I was told that a better approach would be to make some kind of a "Collection". This is how my List looks like now:

```
class MyClassCollection : List<MyClass>
{

}
```

As I understand it is better because I can now use my own methods and for example override `.Add()`.

So my "By the way"-question is: Is that true?

I created `MyClassCollection myClassCollection = new MyClassCollection();` and I added some `MyClass` objects to it. But how do I sort it by alphabetial order of `name`?

If it was a list I could sort it with this:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
myList.Add(myClassObject1);
myList.Add(myClassObject2);
myList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
```

But:

```
MyClassCollection myClassCollection = new MyClassCollection();
myClassCollection.Add(myClassObject1);
myClassCollection.Add(myClassObject2);
myClassCollection = myClassCollection.OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
```

does not work, as the `ToList()` method returns an object of type `List<MyClass>` and not a `MyClassCollection` object.

Comment: You have the `List<T>.Sort()` method at your disposal. And no, you don't have to create custom collection classes for every list/collection in your code.

Comment: you should not subclass from list<T> or any other collection unless you want to add extra functionality to that classes. normaly you work directly with the generic types

Comment: Make the class ICompare : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: _So my "By the way"-question is: Is that true?_ You may have a look at  [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know who told you to make a collection for this but its really not necessary and just hides the fact that at the end of the day its just a generic list. Its honestly worse to obfuscate this way. Anyone looking at the collection in code would assume there is special logic beyond a generic list when there isnt.

Comment: In winforms and WPF, you'll see classes like ["ItemCollection"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcollection?view=netframework-4.8). Types for properties of UI controls have special requirements: No generics, to begin with. Use those types as an example (or just use those types) if and only if you're writing a control.

Comment: How does it "not work"? Does it not compile, does it throw an exception of does it return unexpected results?